# Is it possible to draw YUV422 and YUV420 texture using openGL

Tags: opengl

How could I draw the above format texture using the openGL shaders?
And how could I pass the data to the shader using glTexImage2d?

Comment: Because the planes are in different resolution, you will need to pass them separately. And I doubt that it's going to be more efficient than simply converting to RGB beforehand.

Comment: you mean converting using CPU? is there a way to do things on GPU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](http://www.fourcc.org/source/YUV420P-OpenGL-GLSLang.c) is an example using SDL that shows how to pass YUV420 data to a fragment shader, which then converts it to RGB to write it to the framebuffer:

```
/*
 * Very simple example of how to perform YUV->RGB (YCrCb->RGB)
 * conversion with an OpenGL fragmen shader. The data (not included)
 * is presumed to be three files with Y, U and V samples for a 720x576
 * pixels large image.
 *
 * Note! The example uses NVidia extensions for rectangular textures
 * to make it simpler to read (non-normalised coordinates).
 * Rewriting it without the extensions is quite simple, but left as an
 * exercise to the reader. (The trick is that the shader must know the
 * image dimensions instead)
 *
 * The program also does not check to see if the shader extensions are
 * available - this is after all just a simple example.
 *
 * This code is released under a BSD style license. Do what you want, but
 * do not blame me.
 *
 * Peter Bengtsson, Dec 2004.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glext.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int Quit=0;

static int B_WIDTH=640;
static int B_HEIGHT=480;

int main(int cnt,char *arg[])
{
SDL_Surface *Win=NULL;
GLubyte *Ytex,*Utex,*Vtex;
SDL_Event evt;
int i;
GLhandleARB FSHandle,PHandle;
char *s;
FILE *fp;

char *FProgram=
  "uniform sampler2DRect Ytex;\n"
  "uniform sampler2DRect Utex,Vtex;\n"
  "void main(void) {\n"
  "  float nx,ny,r,g,b,y,u,v;\n"
  "  vec4 txl,ux,vx;"
  "  nx=gl_TexCoord[0].x;\n"
  "  ny=576.0-gl_TexCoord[0].y;\n"
  "  y=texture2DRect(Ytex,vec2(nx,ny)).r;\n"
  "  u=texture2DRect(Utex,vec2(nx/2.0,ny/2.0)).r;\n"
  "  v=texture2DRect(Vtex,vec2(nx/2.0,ny/2.0)).r;\n"

  "  y=1.1643*(y-0.0625);\n"
  "  u=u-0.5;\n"
  "  v=v-0.5;\n"

  "  r=y+1.5958*v;\n"
  "  g=y-0.39173*u-0.81290*v;\n"
  "  b=y+2.017*u;\n"

  "  gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,1.0);\n"
  "}\n";


if(!SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)) {

  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER,1);

  Win=SDL_SetVideoMode(B_WIDTH,B_HEIGHT,32,SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_ANYFORMAT|SDL_OPENGL);

  if(Win) {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,B_WIDTH,0,B_HEIGHT,-1,1);
    glViewport(0,0,B_WIDTH,B_HEIGHT);
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.84,0.0);
    glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT,GL_NICEST);

    /* Set up program objects. */
    PHandle=glCreateProgramObjectARB();
    FSHandle=glCreateShaderObjectARB(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_ARB);

    /* Compile the shader. */
    glShaderSourceARB(FSHandle,1,&FProgram,NULL);
    glCompileShaderARB(FSHandle);

    /* Print the compilation log. */
    glGetObjectParameterivARB(FSHandle,GL_OBJECT_COMPILE_STATUS_ARB,&i);
    s=malloc(32768);
    glGetInfoLogARB(FSHandle,32768,NULL,s);
    printf("Compile Log: %s\n", s);
    free(s);

    /* Create a complete program object. */
    glAttachObjectARB(PHandle,FSHandle);
    glLinkProgramARB(PHandle);

    /* And print the link log. */
    s=malloc(32768);
    glGetInfoLogARB(PHandle,32768,NULL,s);
    printf("Link Log: %s\n", s);
    free(s);

    /* Finally, use the program. */
    glUseProgramObjectARB(PHandle);

    /* Load the textures. */
    Ytex=malloc(414720);
    Utex=malloc(103680);
    Vtex=malloc(103680);

    fp=fopen("Image.Y","rb");
    fread(Ytex,414720,1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("Image.U","rb");
    fread(Utex,103680,1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("Image.V","rb");
    fread(Vtex,103680,1,fp);
    fclose(fp);

    /* This might not be required, but should not hurt. */
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    /* Select texture unit 1 as the active unit and bind the U texture. */
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    i=glGetUniformLocationARB(PHandle,"Utex");
    glUniform1iARB(i,1);  /* Bind Utex to texture unit 1 */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,1);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_DECAL);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,0,GL_LUMINANCE,376,288,0,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Utex);

    /* Select texture unit 2 as the active unit and bind the V texture. */
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    i=glGetUniformLocationARB(PHandle,"Vtex");
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,2);
    glUniform1iARB(i,2);  /* Bind Vtext to texture unit 2 */

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_DECAL);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,0,GL_LUMINANCE,376,288,0,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Vtex);

    /* Select texture unit 0 as the active unit and bind the Y texture. */
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    i=glGetUniformLocationARB(PHandle,"Ytex");
    glUniform1iARB(i,0);  /* Bind Ytex to texture unit 0 */
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,3);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV,GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_DECAL);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_NV,0,GL_LUMINANCE,752,576,0,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Ytex);

    /* Simple loop, just draws the image and waits for quit. */
    while(!Quit) {
      if(SDL_PollEvent(&evt)) {
        switch(evt.type) {
        case  SDL_KEYDOWN:
        case  SDL_QUIT:
          Quit=1;
        break;
        }
      }

      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      /* Draw image (again and again). */

      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i(0,0);
        glVertex2i(0,0);
        glTexCoord2i(720,0);
        glVertex2i(B_WIDTH,0);
        glTexCoord2i(720,576);
        glVertex2i(B_WIDTH,B_HEIGHT);
        glTexCoord2i(0,576);
        glVertex2i(0,B_HEIGHT);
      glEnd();

      /* Flip buffers. */

      glFlush();
      SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

      sleep(1);
    } /* while(!Quit) */

    /* Clean up before exit. */

    glUseProgramObjectARB(0);
    glDeleteObjectARB(sprog);

    free(Ytex);
    free(Utex);
    free(Vtex);

  } else {
    fprintf(stderr,"Unable to create primary surface. \"%s\".\n",SDL_GetError());
  }
  SDL_Quit();
} else {
  fprintf(stderr,"Initialisation failed. \"%s\".\n",SDL_GetError());
}

return(0);
}
```

Converting the example code to straight OpenGL/GLSL (or other shader platform) should be straightforward.

Note that this sample just loads and renders a single frame of data. Generally in a video player, you'd want to update the images plane every frame with new data (eg. with either `glTexImage2D` or `glMapBuffer`). How exactly you do that, depends on where the video data is coming from.

If you are interested in decoding other formats (eg. YUV422), the equation and frequency of the input data may change. [From the same source](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php), there is a description of a large number of YUV formats.